# Create an hybrid TextWidget and TextFieldWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create an immersive experience for the user where he has to complete a sentence.

The difficult part I am facing is to make it 'responsive' so the input text completes the current line and adds a new full line if it goes over the current line.

Here is an exemple in image for the TextField when it is empty:

[image: Empty text field]

Here is an exemple when writing to it:

[image]

Do you have any pointers on how to build such a TextField ?

Comment: Please post what you have tried perhaps as a working snippet so we my better assist you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about remove the border of `textField` and add underline to input text style.

```
TextField(
        style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 15,
    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
  ),  decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          
        ),
      ),
```

some thing like this

**Edit 2:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: Center(child: MyWidget()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String filtext = "    ";
  TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode myFocusNode = FocusNode();
  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    myFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 0, maxHeight: 0),
          child: IntrinsicWidth(
            child: TextField(
              focusNode: myFocusNode,
              controller: myController,
              onChanged: (value) {
                filtext = value;
                if (value.length <= 0) {
                  filtext = "    ";
                }
                setState(() {});
              },
              style: TextStyle(
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, border: InputBorder.none),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {});
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode);
                myFocusNode = FocusNode();
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(text: ' I am '),
                    TextSpan(
                        text: " $filtext ",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        )),
                    TextSpan(text: ' Thank you for coming'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: The issue here is to concatenate both the question which is a `Text` widget and the TextField widget to get the input not decoration

Comment: @ColinLazarini hmm, how about the work around like hide the `TextField` and make use `RichText` to simulate the work. i have edited my answer try and tweak it. :)

Comment: That is exactly it ! Very cool idea to hide the real input and put it in the RichText. Thanks a lot

Comment: :) you are welcome hope you do the tweak and adjustments as you need